# Points rules for an online community

Tags: best-practice

Let's say we have a very big directory based on community, members of which participate on forum and write reviews.

Their main counts are number of reviews, number of posts in forum, and reactions received in both. There are also ratios in both reviews / reactions, and forum posts / reactions (so if someone has posted 10 reviews and received 150 reactions, his ratio in reviews is 15, etc.)

All those can be "translated" into points through "trophies". Simple condition is to get x points if u post 10 reviews f.e. But,

I want to make trophies based on conditions with priority to ratios. F.e. member with 100 reviews gets no points. He will get points if the ratio reviews / reactions is high. I want to also combine those conditions. F.e. for reviews, one member should post more than x number of reviews to start receiving trophies and therefore points.

Some actual examples from our community.

Reviewers

(Top member) 229 reviews, 4654 review score, 20.3 ratio (very good member) 148 reviews, 4045 review score, 27.3 ratio (very good member)reviews 95, 2681 review score, 28.2211 ratio Forum is a little bit different because u have members with up to 100k posts there.

In few words I want to reward acceptance from other members and participation.

Does anybody have anything to propose of some scales of points system that would make sense? Some basic logic. Is there any similar example from some other online community?

I would very much appreciate any help. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I'm not really sure if this question is a good fit for UX.SE, but I'm also not sure on which other SE site it fits ...

Comment: @Glorfindel I guess there is a part of UX design that focuses on gamification and the design/interactions involved. I suppose some examples of points systems in other types of applications can be provided as a reference to answers given.

Comment: I thought stack exchange’s system is scalable and it also rewards users who give constructive q&a. So I’m not sure in your opinion what’s the difference between stack exchange and the forum that you’re building. Maybe can share the differences (in addition to the scale of 100k posts per user) so that we can give suggestions for. You can also tweak the question to post on Game Design SE if you want to gamify the system.

Answer (score 0):

Something that I found interesting when thinking about the points system in UXSE is that there is no gradual 'oxidation' of points that have been accrued from the past, hence it has exactly the same value as before. This makes it very difficult for people to rise through the rankings, especially if you happened to have asked or answered a very topical question from a while ago.

There are of course some guidelines that you can take to create a community that you want to encourage to be actively participating, and you have already mentioned some of them. However, you also want to make sure that people don't game the rules for their own gain.

In order to establish some structure for the points system, you have to establish some ground rules first:

- What is the relative weighting between posts and reviews? This will drive the community towards more posts or reviews based on what you want to achieve, taking into consideration the effort and quality that you want from the posts as opposed to the reviews.
- What is the relative weighting between posts/reviews and reactions? This will help shift the community towards more passive or active participation, and perhaps provide an easier way for new users to participate.
- What is the difference between a reaction for a post compared to a reaction for a review?
- How many different tiers do you anticipate will be required to separate or reward the different types of community members given the size and variety of topics involved? You can also start by creating the basic tiers, and then increasing them as required.